# Create type alias inside of generic class

Tags: scala

I need some way to define a type alias inside of class using its type parameters

```
class ToMap[Key, Value] {
  type MapType = Map[Key, Value]
}

val z: ToMap[Int, Int].MapType = Map((1, 1))
```

This example does not work because `type MapType` is a type member, not type alias, so it will not compile.

Is there some other way that would allow to get type alias using generic class?

In general I need some way to get a different type using a type of generic class, that is make some type transformation. And afterwards I want to reuse the transformed type as a type parameter for other class.

Comment: Would you provide us a minimal example that illustrate your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you want to use path-dependent type:

```
  class ToMap[Key, Value] {
    type MapType = Map[Key, Value]
  }

  val a = new ToMap[Int, Int]
  val z: a.MapType = Map((1, 1))
```

or

```
  val z2: ToMap[Int, Int]#MapType = Map((1, 1))
```

Comment: ```val z2: ToMap[Int, Int]#MapType = Map((1, 1))``` is exactly what I needed, thank you!